# Matrix Multiplication In C

Tags: c, math, matrix

I'm trying to solve a matrix multiplication problem with C. Matrix sizes given in problem (2x2)
I wrote this code but it doesn't print result as I expect. I think I'm missing a point about rules of C.

What is my mistake in this code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int matA[2][2]={0,1,2,3};
    int matB[2][2]={0,1,2,3};
    int matC[2][2];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                matC[i][j] += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
            }
            printf("%d\n",matC[i][j]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Printing Result:

```
2 
3 
4195350
11
```

Comment: Thank You All. But Why three values are correct then just one wrong ? (Same value is wrong all the time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in the line

```
matC[i][j] += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
```

you are adding things to matC, but when you create it, you don't initialize it, so it has garbage.

You sould do something like:

`int matC[2][2] = {0}` which will initialize all the matrix with 0's

Comment: Thank You All. But Why three values are correct then just one wrong ? (Same value is wrong all the time)

Comment: It is implementation dependant, it can have any value.. The fact that it has the values you say should be because of the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the matrix multiplication code I use:

```
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<K;j++){
        matC[i][j]=0;
        for(k=0;k<N;k++){
            matC[i][j]+=matA[i][k]*matB[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

big thing is setting the answer matrix to zero (as the rest have said without code).

Comment: what is M, N and K?

Comment: @eri0o Generally, its: MxN size matrix  with a NxK. M is the rows of Matrix A, K is the columns of Matrix B, and N is the "count" of these parts that you have to add. The N part is also known as the dot product.  Been a while since I have looked at this, so check it over for sure.

Answer (score 5):

matC initially contains some garbage values. Iniatialize the martix to all zeroes. This might solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize elements of `C` to zero first.

Answer (score 2):

You can have matrix multiplication of any given size by user in the following manner :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;

    printf("Enter number of rows and columns for matrix A : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r1,&c1);

    printf("Enter number of rows and columns for matrix B : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r2,&c2);

    int a[r1][c1], b[r2][c2], ab[r1][c2], ba[r2][c1],i,j,k,temp;

    if(c1==r2 && r1==c2)
    {
        printf("\nEnter element in matrix A : ");
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            {
                printf("\n Enter element : ");
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\nEnter element in B : ");
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
            {
                printf("\nEnter element : ");
                scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
            {
                temp=0;
                for(k=0;k<r2;k++)
                {
                    temp+=a[i][k]*b[j][k];
                }
                ab[i][j]=temp;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            {
                temp=0;
                for(k=0;k<r1;k++)
                {
                    temp+=b[i][k]*a[k][j];
                }
                ba[i][j]=temp;
            }
        }
        printf("\nMatrix A : ");
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            printf("\n\t");
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            {
                printf("%d",a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\nMatrix B : ");
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        {
            printf("\n\t");
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
            {
                printf("%d",b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\nMatrix multiplication of A*B : ");
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            printf("\n\t");
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
            {
                printf("\t%d",ab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\nMatrix multiplication of B*A : ");
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        {
            printf("\n\t");
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            {
                printf("\t%d",ba[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else
        printf("\nMatrix Multiplication is not possible...!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `matC` to all zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

If size and dependencies don't matter I would suggest using the GNU Scientific Library.
See here for features: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Scientific_Library

It contains optimized routines for mathematical calculations and is quite fast with some compiler optimizations.

Already used it successful for matrix operations in 3D Development.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html#matrices

Answer (score 0):

You may want to dynamically allocate memory for the resultant matrix.  If so, use `calloc()` to allocate and clear the elements.  `printMatrix()` is called
to print result, but not defined here.

```
/* matrix1: [rows1 x cols1];  matrix2: [rows2 x cols2]; product is
matrix3: [rows1 x cols2] if (cols1 == rows2) is true.  calloc to 
allocate / clear memory for matrix3.  Algorithm is O(n^3) */

float ** matrix3;
if (cols1 == rows2) {  // product matrix can be calculated
    // calloc product matrix3
    matrix3 = (float **)calloc(rows1, sizeof(float *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
        matrix3[i] = (float *)calloc(cols2, sizeof(float));

    int i, j, k;
    float tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols2; j++) {
            tmp = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < rows2; k++)
                tmp += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
            matrix3[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    printMatrix(matrix3, rows1, cols2, 3);
    free(matrix3);
} else {   // cols1 != rows2
    puts("dimensional mismatch; can't multiply matrices");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  main.c
//  Matrix Multiplicatiion.
//
//  Created by Devansh on 15/07/21.
// THIS WORKS FOR ANY MATRIX multiplication 
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arow,acolumn,brow, bcolumn,i,j;
    int MAX=100;
    int a[MAX][MAX];
    int b[MAX][MAX];
    printf("enter rows of matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d", &arow);
    printf("enter columns of matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d", &acolumn);
    printf("enter rows of matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d", &brow);
    printf("enter columns of matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d", &bcolumn);
    if(brow != acolumn){
        printf("sorry we cannot multiply matrix a and b");
    } else {
        printf("enter the elements of matrix a:\n");
        for (i=0;i<arow;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<acolumn;j++) {
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        printf("enter the elements of matrix b:\n");
        for (i=0;i<brow;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<bcolumn;j++) {
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        int product[MAX][MAX];
        int sum=0;
        for (i=0;i<arow;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<bcolumn;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<brow;k++){
                    sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
                product[i][j]= sum;
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<arow;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<bcolumn;j++) {
                printf("%d   ", product[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can find multiplication of 2 matrix of any dimension (like multiplication of 2x3 and 3x2 size matrix)using this code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
     int main()
    {
    int p, q, r, s;
    printf("enter the dimension of first matrix\n");
    scanf("%dx%d", &p, &q);
    printf("enter the dimension of second matrix\n");
    scanf("%dx%d", &r, &s);
    if (q != r)
    {
        printf("multiplication is not possible\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int a[p][q], b[r][s], c[p][s];
        printf("enter the first matrix\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < q; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("enter the second matrix\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < r; k++)
                {
                    sum = sum + (a[i][k] * b[k][j]);
                }
                c[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        printf("resultant matrix is....\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```