# Multiplication of Matrices in C

Tags: c

I have to Input three positive integers n, m, and p. Then input two matrices. The first one is a n (rows) by m (columns) matrix. The second one is a m (rows) by p (columns) matrix then output the matrix product (should be n rows by p columns) and use heap memory to store the matrices. Here is what I have so far,

```
long double adjProduct(int n, int m, int ** matrix)
{
int j, k, l;
long double product = 0.0;
long double temp = 0.0;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {

        if((i + (1*(m - 1))) < n)
        {
            temp = 1;
            for(k = 0; k < m; k++)
                temp *= matrix[i + k][j];

            if(temp > product)
                product = temp;
        }


        if(j + (1*(m-1)) < n)
        {
            temp = 1;

            for(k = 0; k < m; k++)
                temp *= matrix[i][j + k];

            if(temp > product)
                product = temp;
        }



        if((i + (1*(m-1)) < n) && (j + (1*(m-1)) < n))
        {
            temp = 1;

            for(k = 0; k < m; k++)
                temp *= matrix[i + k][j + k];

            if(temp > product)
                product = temp;
        }


        if((i + (1*(m-1)) < n) && (j - (1*(m-1)) >= 0))
        {
            temp = 1;

            for(k = 0; k < m; k++)
                temp *= matrix[i + k][j - k];

            if(temp > product)
                product = temp;
          }

     }
 }

return product;
}

 main(){

int ** matrix;
int n = 0; 
int m = 0;
int i, j;

scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);


matrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*n);
if(matrix == NULL)
    exit(0);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    if(matrix[i] == NULL)
        exit(0);
}

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
}

printf("%.0Lf", adjProduct(n, m, matrix));

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(matrix[i]);

free(matrix);
matrix = NULL;
  }
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: "*All help is appreciated!*" - What do you need help with?

Comment: with modern C, to see how to allocate matrices on the heap could have a look at http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/dont-be-afraid-of-variably-modified-types/ to see how to pass theses beasts to functions https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/vla-as-function-arguments/

Comment: I've sent the current code to my tutor, and he's told me that the matrix multiplication is not correct. I'm confused as to why

Comment: @user1637226 - I assumed you ran it yourself? Did it work correctly? If not, what did it do? Give SO users something to work with. Your question right now, is kind of vague.

Comment: It seems I did miss the multiplication aspect as when I run it myself it simply takes input then closes. I'm confused however, as to where I need to put this multiplication. C isn't my strongest language, I do apologise.

Comment: Start by searching SO for [matrix multiplication C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162467/matrix-multiplication-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Where are you multiplying? Multiplication should be something like this:

```
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<p;j++)
            {
                product[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<m;k++)
                {   
                         product[i][j]+=matrix1[i][k]*matrix2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
```